# How to make authorization to specific field in specific object in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to check privileges to specific field in specific object in database.

Let's make and example. I have Model called `Employee`

```
public class Employee {

    [Key]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Salary { get; set; } // <---- Restricted

    public int BossID { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a few cases:

1. I need to restrict access to specific field `Salary` because I don't want anyone to see each other salary. But HR can see anyone `Salary` and edit it. If I'm this employee I can see my own `Salary`, but cannot edit it.
2. Everyone can see each other job titles, but only HR can edit it. And also boss of that employee, can edit, by employee himself cannot.

Use case:

- I'm manager with RoleID 4. I want to see `Salary` of my `Employee` named John Smith with `EmployeeID` 5. I can do that.
- I'm manager with RoleID 4. I want to see `Salary` of 'Employee`named Mark Twain with`EmployeeID` 8. Mark is not but my directly subordinate. He is from different branch. I cannot do that.
- I'm employee with `EmployeeID` 5 and I want to see my `Salary`. That's allowed.
- I'm employee with `EmployeeID` 5 and I want to edit my own `Salary`. It's forbidden. I get HTTP Error 401.
- I'm from HR. I can see and edit `Salary` of all Employees in company.

I though of something like this:

```
public class Access {
  [Required]
  public int RoleID { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string TableName { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string ColumnName { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public int RowID { get; set; }
}
```

And then check (by `Authorize` attribute) if specific role (boss, HR or something) has access to specific field (for example `Salary`) for specific data (for example `Employee` with id 22). That's a lot of "specific"by the way.

How should I do it? Is my idea 'OK'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement 2 different methods. One is for the HR when requesting the data, and the other is for the simple user. Then you never should return the whole object (json), instead, create some DTOs (Data Transfer Object) that holds the desired data. So lets make an example:

```
public class DTOGetEmployeeByEmployee {

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int BossID { get; set; }
}

public class DTOGetEmployeeByHR {

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Salary { get; set; }

    public int BossID { get; set; }
}
```

Once a user requests that employee, get it from the Database, and then convert it into the desired DTO. Best way I saw so far is using AutoMapper to do so:

```
Mapper.Map<DTOxxxx>(yourObject);
```

You can also use the [Authorize] Attribute to check if the User is HR or an Employee. I did this  multiple times combined with JWT-Token.

```
public class EmployeeController
{
    [Authorize("HR")]
    [HttpGet, Route("GetForHR")]
    public IActionResult Get(int employeeID)
    {
        // Note: this is just a sample out of my head, so there will be adjustments needed in order to run that

        // Check if the HR is allowed to access the Employees data

        // Get the Employee by its ID
        var emp = ...;

        // Convert it to the DTO
        var dto = Mapper.Map<DTOGetEmployee>(emp);

        // return the dto
        return Ok(dto);
    }
}
```

I bet there are plenty of better solutions out there, but for me, this is super simple, wasy to reimplement in other applications and there is no palpable performance loss

Comment: How about updating models?

Comment: Make a DTOUpdateEmployeeByHR. This Model holds all the neccessary data needed to update the column. Then you simply convert the DTO back to the base Model

Comment: Instead of fighting with privileges I should just simply redirect models based on role. Sound great, I'll try it.

Comment: Exactly, actually I am developing an App which handles 10+ different roles, with completly different ways to get / update / delete data. My approach works very well for my needs and I think it can fit into yours. One problem of this is getting duplacte code, but if you're clever, you find a way to sum up the duplicates

Comment: Okay but... how about access to specific records?

Comment: What do you exactly mean? If you want to have Employee with ID 15 for example?

Comment: Let's assume, that some role (for example boss) can change salary for Employees with ID 12, 13, 14, but cannot change other Employees. Or manager can only see Salary of his own subordinate Employees 16, 17, 18.

Comment: If you want the HR only Access spefic IDs, you should manage that inside your Controller. But this is not the way you should do this

Comment: I guess, that correct way to do this is too broad for comment. Could you modify your answer and add correct way?

Comment: I think so too, but I still don't know what exactly you want. Do you really want the HR to be not allowed to access data of Employee 15, or does the HR be only allowed to access data of Employees with a specific Property, like beeing in the same branch?

Comment: The second one. Only HR (or other user like boss, manager etc.) should access specific Property (for example Salary) for specific Employees...

Comment: Yeah sure, but what are specific employees? Only the IDs or do they have a specific Property?

Comment: Only IDs. Because all Employees has `Salary`. That make sense. But not anybody can see and/or edit Salary.

Comment: This is really not the way you want to do it. Never filter by the ID, you better should implement any other filter criteria like roleID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181875/discussion-between-morasiu-and-daniel-dirtynative-martin).

Answer (score 6):

In case when logic is less complicated or more generic, it's possible to set [custom output formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to prevent some fields to be written into the respose.

The approach has next problems:

1. Shouldn't handle complicated logic. As it causes business logic spread to the multiple places
2. Replaces default serialization. So if there are specific serialization settings are set in `Startup`, then it should be transfered

Let's see an example. 
There could be a custom attrbute like

```
public class AuthorizePropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public AuthorizePropertyAttribute(string role) => Role = role;
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Then output formatter could be like:

```
public class AuthFormatter : TextOutputFormatter
{
    public AuthFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, 
        Encoding selectedEncoding)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
        {
            ContractResolver = new AuthorizedPropertyContractResolver(context.HttpContext.User)
        };
        await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Object, settings));
    }
}
```

That would require

```
public class AuthorizedPropertyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public AuthorizedPropertyContractResolver(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        User = user;
    }

    public ClaimsPrincipal User { get; }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, 
        MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var result = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        result.ShouldSerialize = e =>
        {
            var role = member.GetCustomAttribute<AuthorizePropertyAttribute>()?.Role;
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(role) ? true : User.IsInRole(role);
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

Registration:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new AuthFormatter());
});
```

In that case Response for simple user will lack of the Salary field `{"Id":1,"Name":"John"}` at the same time manager will see the full response
`{"Id":1,"Name":"John","Salary":100000}`, ofcourse the property "Salary" should have attribute set

```
[AuthorizeProperty("Boss")]
public double Salary { get; set; }
```

Comment: Oh... That's quite a better approach. The problem was from my old work project, but I really appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: Great answer and a really clever way to solve this problem. However, that leaves me wondering:

Surely there's *got* to be more companies/people that need to authorize a user to change their own username, for example, but not their salary.

How is this problem solved usually? Does having to do something like in your answer (custom output formatter) hint at possibly having a bad application architecture?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to bring the approach to the complex/specific business logic cases. For the input data basic request data validation would be preferable. About the sample: salary change should causes an error and, most probably, that should be found on the testing phase as UI/design bug.